# Layout not working as expected (block level elements, width: 50%)

Tags: html, css

Could somebody explain why the following code doesn't work?

http://jsfiddle.net/eL9hpcL9/

#### html

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="sidebar">1</div>
    <div class="sidebar">2</div>
</div>
```

#### css

```
#content {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


.sidebar {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I would expect the sidebars to be side by side, but they are not. I don't even know where to start. I know I can use `float: left`, but how can I get this working with `inline-block`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remove **white space** between divs as it is also counted and don't let 50% width work.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="sidebar">1</div><!--
    --><div class="sidebar">2</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eL9hpcL9/1/

Comment: Wow, almost speechless.

Comment: When you know ;) cheers.

Comment: @DamienRoche http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: That's a really interesting solution, but it does require semantic knowledge of the HTML.  I think the `font-size:0` on the parent is the more commonly used one, but has many of the same non-sensical caveats.  This is elegant in its own way.  I like it.

Comment: I don't think I've run into this problem before because I've been using template engines, which I imagine are stripping whitespace.

Comment: Divs without float aren't used so much, that's why it's not a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

"display: inline-block" property adding an extra space. Much better if you use the "float: left" instead of "display: inline-block", but you can add a negative margin to the left and right to kill the extra spaces. eg. "margin: 0 -2px;".

Comment: You really don't want to start introducing negative margins on layout just to accommodate white-space.  It's a bad precedent.  Especially since white-space can render differently based on the font being displayed on a user's screen.

Answer (score 0):

So just style the content with display table and then the sidebar with display as table-cell and the width you need

```
#content {
   padding : 0;
   margin : 0;
   display : table;
 }


 .sidebar {
     display : table-cell;
     width: 50%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
```